# column reference is ambiguous in Postgresql query even when subquery has that column explicitly named

Tags: sql, postgresql

For the query below I get an error:

```
[42702] ERROR: column reference "updated_at" is ambiguous Position: 5193
```

on the line with:

```
execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.created_at
```

In the query below:

```
WITH max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field AS (SELECT public.execution_data.job_base_step_id,
                                                  public.execution_data.execution_type,
                                                  public.execution_data.field_id,
                                                  MAX(public.execution_data.seq_id) max_seq_id
                                           FROM public.execution_data
                                           WHERE public.execution_data.execution_type IN (1, 7)
                                           GROUP BY public.execution_data.job_base_step_id,
                                                    public.execution_data.execution_type,
                                                    public.execution_data.field_id),
     execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field AS (SELECT public.execution_data.id,
                                                                    public.execution_data.seq_id,
                                                                    public.execution_data.seq_id,
                                                                    public.execution_data.step_id,
                                                                    public.execution_data.field_id,
                                                                    public.execution_data.job_base_step_id,
                                                                    public.execution_data.job_id,
                                                                    public.execution_data.data,
                                                                    public.execution_data.step_complete,
                                                                    public.execution_data.created_at,
                                                                    public.execution_data.updated_at AS updated_at,
                                                                    public.execution_data.execution_type,
                                                                    public.execution_data.step_group_id,
                                                                    public.execution_data.user_id,
                                                                    public.execution_data.step_non_applicable,
                                                                    public.execution_data.device_id,
                                                                    public.execution_data.device_seq_id,
                                                                    public.execution_data.updated_at,
                                                                    public.execution_data.pending,
                                                                    public.execution_data.client_created_at,
                                                                    public.execution_data.step_state,
                                                                    public.execution_data.step_elapsed_duration_user
                                                             FROM public.execution_data
                                                                      INNER JOIN max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field
                                                                                 ON max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.job_base_step_id =
                                                                                    public.execution_data.job_base_step_id AND
                                                                                    max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.execution_type =
                                                                                    public.execution_data.execution_type AND
                                                                                    max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.field_id =
                                                                                    public.execution_data.field_id)
SELECT CASE
           WHEN (
                   public.fields.job_resolved_names ->>
                   concat(execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.job_id, ':',
                          execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.job_base_step_id) IS NOT NULL)
               THEN (
                   public.fields.job_resolved_names ->>
                   concat(execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.job_id, ':',
                          execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.job_base_step_id))
           ELSE public.fields.key END                                             AS name
     , execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.id                     AS instance_id
     , execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.field_id
     , execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.job_id
     , execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.created_at
     , execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.updated_at
     , CASE
           WHEN execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.data::jsonb -> 'number' IS NOT NULL THEN
                   execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.data::jsonb ->> 'number'
           ELSE NULL END                                                          AS field_value_number
     , CASE
           WHEN execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.data::jsonb -> 'text' IS NOT NULL THEN
                   execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.data::jsonb ->> 'text'
           ELSE NULL END                                                          AS field_value_text
     , execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.data::jsonb ->> 'date' AS field_value_timestamp
     , CASE
           WHEN execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.execution_type = 1
               THEN execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.data::boolean
           ELSE FALSE END                                                         AS is_marked_na
     , execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.user_id
     , execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.step_id
FROM execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field
         JOIN public.fields ON public.fields.id = execution_data_of_max_seq_id_per_job_type_and_field.field_id;
```

Not sure why this happens as the subquery has that column labeled explicitly. If needed I can provide the schema for the tables but I'm sure it's some easy thing I can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely that you are returning the same column twice, with the same name.

```
public.execution_data.updated_at AS updated_at, -- First copy
public.execution_data.execution_type,
public.execution_data.step_group_id,
public.execution_data.user_id,
public.execution_data.step_non_applicable,
public.execution_data.device_id,
public.execution_data.device_seq_id,
public.execution_data.updated_at, -- Second copy
```

I'd suggest removing that first line (First copy) above.